# How to keep running screen command even when the admin changes chmod of screen to 700 or 777

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am a system administrator. The users of the system use screen for running their programs in background. However, it so happens that if I change the mode of screen to 700 or 777 while the users programs are running then their programs stops. When the users run

```
      screen -r process_id
```

then it shows the process can not be resumed. Can someone guide as to how should users run their program such that even after a chmod of screen to 777 and 700 their programs do not stop.

Comment: why would you change the access rights of a binary if you don't want to prevent somebody from using it?

Comment: Why would someone change the mode of *anything* to 777 (which gives all users read/write/execute access)? If you change the permissions to 700 then obviously only the owner of the `screen` executable can use it; that's the point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just tested it out and the default permissions on screen are

```
-rwxr-sr-x 1 root utmp 421640 Sep 16  2012 /usr/bin/screen
```

So, its obvious when you run:

```
root@system:~# chmod 777 /usr/bin/screen
```

It becomes:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root utmp 421640 Sep 16  2012 /usr/bin/screen
```

Which removes the SGID bit from the executable. Its significance is covered here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid. Utmp is explained here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utmp

In other words since you are unsetting the SGID bit on screen, UTMP loses permissions over screen executable, and thereby loses track of the screen session.

To change it back to the original permissions you can run:

```
root@system:~# chmod 2755 /usr/bin/screen
```

**A word of advice in the end: Please don't change permissions on system executables without knowing what impact it will have.**
You can always try these things out on some dummy/test machines to gain an understanding of the impact your changes will have on the system.

Comment: By changing the permissions to `777`, you're also giving every user on the system permission to modify the executable, deliberately, accidentally, and/or maliciously.

Comment: Yes, but i thought it's (permissions, 777 etc) part of Linux basics all System Admins are taught when they start learning Linux.